# Can I use MAX4644EUT to drive pin high or low?

Tags: multiplexer

I've a module that operates at +5V.

Instead of using 2x MOSFET or transistor + MOSFET to drive the MODULE.VCCIN either +5v / gnd, can I use the MAX4644 instead?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqGoBp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this schematic I would drive either NO or NC to COM by using an ESP32.IO pin.

Edit: the 5V module is going to draw 80mA. If max is not right is there an IC much like this one that i could use within datasheet spec?

Comment: A MOSFET is a type of transistor. Do you mean BJT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issues with schematic in the question

The schematic in the question shows:

1. 3.3 V connected to the `V+` pin of the [MAX4644](https://www.analog.com/en/products/max4644.html).
2. 5 V connected to the `NC` pin of the MAX4644

I.e. the voltage on the `NC` pin is greater than that on `V+` pin by 1.7 V. From the ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM RATINGS of the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX4644.pdf) this is not allowed, and will cause the internal ESD diodes to conduct:

[image]

Also, the maximum continuous current of the MAX4644 is ±20mA which is less than the 80 mA current draw of the load.

### Consider a Load Switch, instead of an Analog Switch

The question considers an *Analog Switch* which is not really intended to power loads.

A *Load Switch* is probably a better option. TI (for example) provide a range of *Load Switch* devices, with different number of channels, maximum current and maximum voltages. [Load switches](https://www.ti.com/power-management/power-switches/load-switches/products.html#480=1%3B1&1685=0.08%3B0.5&) is the list filtered for:

- A single channel
- Maximum current in the range 0.08 A to 0.5 A

For which at the time of answering there are 13 products matching the selection.

Picked the [TPS22948 5.5-V, 240-mA Current Limited Load Switch with Reverse Current Blocking](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS22948) as an example, which has the following characteristics which should be meet the requirements in the question:

1. Input operating voltage range 2.5 V to 5.5 V
2. Maximum current of 240 mA
3. ON-Resistance (RON): 450 mΩ (max -40°C to 85°C), so drops a maximum of 36 mV at 80 mA.
4. The TPS22948 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps22948.pdf) shows the  V<sub>IH</sub> ON Pin High Voltage Range min 1 V. This is compatible with a 3.3 V GPIO from the ESP32; the ESP32 [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf) shows V<sub>OH</sub> High-level output voltage as 0.8×VDD.
5. 6-Pin SC-70 package, so similar to the 6 pin SOT23 package of the MAX4644EUT.
6. When power is first applied, a smart pull down is used to keep the ON pin from floating until system sequencing is complete.

Comment: Thanks @Chester Gillon, i've updated the question with information about the external 5V module. If you could update your answer with the info i added and hopefully a max4644 alternative it would be very helpful.

Comment: @AndreaBaccega Will the supply for the ESP32 and 5 V supply for the module always be present at the same time, or may one supply be present without the other? That could affect the selection of a solid state switch, depending upon if the solid state switch includes internal diodes between the supply and switched pins (as the MAX4644 does).

Comment: yes i have 5V in and an LDO for 3v3 for the esp32.

Comment: @AndreaBaccega I have edited the answer to suggest how to select an alternative, and listed one example device. Tried to keep the answer generic, since requests for specific devices are considered off-topic.

Comment: thanks a lot chester

Comment: as a follow up @chester gillon, i was reading datasheet and did not find  this "VOH High-level output voltage 0.8×VDD" .

I did not find VOH or the 0.8xVDD. can you please explain? BTW answer accepted thanks a lot again

Comment: @AndreaBaccega I have edited the answer to try and clarify where "VOH" came from.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The NC pin has 5V and it can't exceed the 3.3V supply on V+ pin.

Also the analog switch is suitable for switcing low current analog signals. If the module draws any significant amount of current above 10mA, this is a wrong component for the job.